# App crashes on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I posted before, but I was focusing on why my app was crashing from Testflight but from Xcode. The general answers involved Debug vs. Release mode, but that doesn't make sense in this case, because it DOES run on iPad from TF, and not from iPhone. Touching a certain sprite is supposed to open a menu, and it makes it crash on iPhone, but not iPad.

So I have a game (using Sprite Kit) which sometimes crash when a certain method finishes running. It does this 10% (or less) of the time when I run it on my iPhone 5s from Xcode, but if I upload to Testflight, it does it 100% of the time.

[image]

Xcode doesn't give me great debugging info, it shows a green breakpoint line in main.m on this line:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

and on the left panel it says this happens in:

```
Thread 1:

Queue: com.apple.spritekit.renderQueue 0 SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp(std::__1::vector >&, SKRenderQuadPool&, SKCSprite const*, _GLKMatrix4 const&, float, unsigned int&, bool)const
```

and I see an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` in this line:

```
0x1015bc663: movq 16(%rbx), %rcx
```

I will attach a pic actually of the surrounding stuff

I am bad at debugging and I don't know what to do. One notable thing is that this never happens in the iPad version. I'm very confused as to why it would happen sometimes but not always.

---

UPDATE: I have tracked this down a bit further. Here is the code causing it:

```
NSString *animation1File = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MENU-ready-to-animate-%@_00001",devicePrefix] ofType:@"jpg"];
NSString *animation3File = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MENU-ready-to-animate-%@_00003",devicePrefix] ofType:@"jpg"];
NSString *animation5File = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MENU-ready-to-animate-%@_00005",devicePrefix] ofType:@"jpg"];

UIImage *animation1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:animation1File];
UIImage *animation3 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:animation3File];
UIImage *animation5 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:animation5File];

NSMutableArray *menuAnimations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [SKTexture textureWithImage:animation1],
                                  [SKTexture textureWithImage:animation3],
                                  [SKTexture textureWithImage:animation5],
                                  nil];

[SKTexture preloadTextures:menuAnimations withCompletionHandler:^(void) {

    menuNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MENU-ready-to-animate-%@_00000.jpg", devicePrefix]];
    menuNode.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
    menuNode.zPosition = 55;
    menuNode.name = @"menu";
    [self addChild:menuNode];
    openMenu = [SKAction animateWithTextures:menuAnimations timePerFrame:0.05];
    SKAction *showWeapons = [SKAction runBlock:^(void) {
        [self showWeapons];
        menuShowing = YES;
        //[self addChild:menuCheckMark];
        //[self addChild:menuCheckMarkLink];
    }];
    [menuNode runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[openMenu, showWeapons]]];
}];
```

So the important thing here is that I am loading the images with **SKTexture textureWithImage:** but if I change it to **SKTexture textureWithImageName:** then the problem disappears

```
NSMutableArray *menuAnimations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                   [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MENU-ready-to-animate-%@_00001.jpg",devicePrefix]],
                                   [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MENU-ready-to-animate-%@_00003.jpg",devicePrefix]],
                                   [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"MENU-ready-to-animate-%@_00005.jpg",devicePrefix]],
```

I actually was using **textureWithImageNamed** originally, but the memory the textures use was never unloading, and an Apple engineer told me that using **textureWithImage** would cause the memory to unload faster, which it **did**, but I guess it's causing this.

Can anyone replicate this, or come up with an explanation? It's all over my head, so I don't know if it's a Sprite Kit bug, or whether it's something I am just doing wrong, which is obviously very possible!

Comment: Does it crash on iPad or iPhone? You say in the title it crashes on iPad, but you contradict yourself in the second to last sentence.

Comment: Without seeing any of your code this can not be debugged. This is a crash deep inside the SKView (closed source) update loop so the best you can do is to try to narrow down the cause of the issue by gradually removing code from your project until the issue goes away. Then re-add some code until the issue re-apears. Then you hopefully have narrowed it down to a couple lines of code that you could post here.

Comment: fori: Oops, I messed up the title, it crashes on iPhone, good catch. LearnCocos2D: Okay, that's very handy,. I'll try that!

Comment: Update: I narrowed it down (and worked around it), and I have updated the original post with the details. I am still very confused as to why the code breaks on iPhone and not iPad. Or why it breaks at all I guess!

Comment: Have you tried turning on NSZombies and see when the memory is being released? ImageWithName makes a cached version of the image so It may not be getting released in that situation